# русская речь, выражения

Tags: словообразование

оптимизм уменьшается или как правильно?

Answer (score 2):

Оптимизм подобен веществу: его бывает мало, но он не бывает "маленьким"; его может стать меньше, но "уменьшается" не он сам, а его количество, либо количество его носителей.  Поэтому индивидуальный оптимизм, скорее, "**убывает**", чем "уменьшается". Коллективный же оптимизм, измеряемый статистическим *количеством оптимистов*, "**падает**", реже "уменьшается". В обоих случаях оптимизм может "**идти на убыль**"; в результате, его (количество) может "**поубавиться**".

Comment: Александр, глагол ''уменьшиться'' как раз предполагает уменьшение в количестве. Убывать и уменьшиться - синонимы. См. словарную фиксацию.

Answer (score 1):

Да, всё правильно: оптимизм уменьшается.

Примеры

Когда оптимизм уменьшается, люди прибегают к психотерапии.

Азия: оптимизм уменьшился.

Оптимизм предпринимателей продолжает уменьшаться.

Answer (score 1):

Оптимизм как состояние не может уменьшаться. Оно — состояние — улавливается, выражая себя только **опосредованно**: оптимизмом в *глазах*, *движениях*, *голосе*. Его проявление бывает более или менее явным, и тогда это явное можно выразить относительно какого-то известного уровня, то есть сравнительно, не количественно: *оптимизма в высказываниях стало меньше*, как и *воды в реке*, *смысла в поступках*.